# Assign a filetype when editing any file from a directory

Tags: autocmd, filetype

## The context

I store all my shell scripts insde the `$HOME/.bin` directory. Because of this, I've been looking for a way to set the `sh` filetype whenever I open a file located in that directory.  So, I've created the following autocommand

```
$ cat ~/.vim/ftdetect/sh.vim
au BufNewFile,BufRead $HOME/.bin/* setf sh
```

which is stored inside the `~/.vim/ftdetect/sh.vim` file.  I wrote that command because I found the following statements in the `vim` help (`:h autocmd-patterns`)

```
2. When there is a '/' in the pattern, Vim checks for a match against both the
   short file name (as you typed it) and the full file name (after expanding
   it to a full path and resolving symbolic links).
```

```
Environment variables can be used in a pattern: >
    :autocmd BufRead $VIMRUNTIME/doc/*.txt  set expandtab
```

## The problem

When editing a file from the `$HOME/.bin` directory, the `sh` filetype is not assigned.

## The question

What I am doing wrong here?

## Additional context

The `~/.bin` directory is a symbolic link (see below) but I don't think this might be causing this

```
$ test -h ~/.bin && echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to `:setf[iletype]` command. From `:h :setf`

> Set the 'filetype' option to {filetype}, but **only if not done yet in a sequence of (nested) autocommands**.

As your `autocmd` is surely run after all the bundled stuff, the filetype for the current buffer might be set already. Then your command has no effect. Use plain `:set filetype=sh` if you're forcefully going to redefine the filetype (however note that it may result in two consecutive `FileType` events for the same buffer).

Comment: I've changed the presented command to `au BufNewFile,BufRead $HOME/.bin/* set ft=sh` and the filetype is properly assigned. Thanks! However, what seems odd to me is that `setf` didn't set the `filetype` even when the `filetype` hasn't been assigned yet to the opened buffer. For isntance, I tried opening a file with name `foobar` under that directory: it hadn't been assigned a `filetype` and the `setf` didn't set it even when there was no `filetype` assigned. Because of this, I consider the statement `only if not done yet in a sequence of (nested) autocommands` to be false.

Comment: @R.Morales That's strange. It should work in that case. That could be some local problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a workaround than a real answer to your question, but it is what I use for this particular case :

```
augroup FileTypeRefresh
    au!
    au BufWrite * if &ft ==# '' | filetype detect | endif
augroup end
```

This uses `filetype detect` when no filetype is set (a bit like `setfiletype` is supposed to behave).

From  `:h :filetype-detect`:

> Use this if you started with an empty file and typed text that makes it
>   possible to detect the file type.  For example, when you entered this in a
>   shell script: "#!/bin/csh".

Compared to your approach:

- Caveat: requires typing something to detect the filetype (the shebang for example)
- Advantage: works for any file, any folder